# Oracle change any string to a number

Tags: oracle

I'm having this problem we have this database witch IDS are stored in `varchar2` type this ids contains Letters.

Is there any solution to convert a string to a number no matter what the value if this string.

for example there is : `SELCT ASCII('t') FROM DUAL; result : 116.`

but `ASCII` accept only one `CHAR` Hope you get the idea. sorry for my english

Comment: Take a look at [to_number](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions191.htm) function

Comment: to_number will raise a error if we give it 't'

Comment: You said you don't care what numeric value is assigned, but you probably do care. Otherwise you can replace all id's with the number 0 (or with a random number, etc.) I assume you need the same ID to be assigned the same number every time, and different ID's to be assigned different ID's. It's not clear how you plan to implement the solution though; ID must be primary key in one table and foreign key in other tables. Updating will be a pain - did you think about it?

Comment: Update will be hell in my case. When i said i don't care about the value i meant if the string is a valid number or a list of letters.  I think i need to create a function for this.

Comment: Functions for this exist already, you don't need to create a new one. I showed one such function in an Answer.

Comment: What version of Oracle do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:  After discussing further with the OP, it turns out he needed a function (in the mathematical sense) from short strings to integers. Such a function is ORA_HASH. The OP decided that ORA_HASH is likely what is needed for his project.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions112.htm#SQLRF06313

**The solution below is kept for historical perspective.**

You could use the analytic function `DENSE_RANK` to assign numbers to strings.

For example:

```
with
     employees ( id, first_name, last_name ) as (
       select 'ABC', 'Jane', 'Smith' from dual union all
       select 'ABD', 'Jane', 'Dryer' from dual union all
       select 'XYZ', 'Mike', 'Lopez' from dual
     )
--  End of simulated inputs (for testing purposes only).
--  Solution (SQL query) begins below this line.
select id, dense_rank() over (order by id) as num_id, first_name, last_name
from   employees
;

ID   NUM_ID  FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME
---  ------  ----------  ---------
ABC       1  Jane        Smith
ABD       2  Jane        Dryer
XYZ       3  Mike        Lopez
```

Comment: But here if the order of the record change the value of num_id changes too.  So ABC will not be 1 always.  What i need is no matter the order of ABC will always be 1. Like mapping a string to a number

Comment: This like select rownum. Or no

Comment: This is like select ROWNUM if all the ID's are different. DENSE_RANK() assigns the same number to the same ID if the ID appears more than once.

Comment: I assume you will use something like this for an `UPDATE` and then you won't need this ever again. So if records (rows) are added in the future, they will be given numeric ID's already. It makes no sense at all to assign numeric ID's, but to continue to assign string ID's to new records in the future.

Comment: i need this records to do some statics but i need to change the ID to integer value. so if the order is changed in the query the Generated ID is changed and we don't need that if it was something like ASCII function so when i pass 'AC' i always get for example `1214` may be i will create a function that loop on the string and convert char by char.

Comment: OK. How long are your ID's? You realize that there is no limit on the length of strings, but there **is** a limit on the size of numbers (38 digits), so you will not be able to do this for arbitrary strings. If all your strings are, for example, at most four characters, then you could take the ASCII code for each character, concatenate them and call the resulting string a number. Is that what you need?

Comment: Ids are 4 chars but i can do sum or equatien

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149376/discussion-between-mathguy-and-cherif-odoo).

Comment: I think ORA_HASH may work i'm not using my compute but i will give it a try. what i need is a method when i pass to it a string value always convert it to the same integer value. if i pass 'ADSD' and it gave me 14256 , next time if i pass 'ADSD' next time i need it to give me 14256 not some rundom number

Comment: I think this is what i want i will accept your answer please edit your answer and put some explanation for this method if you don't mind

Answer (score 2):

use oracle translate method to replace A-Z or a-z characters with numbers.
then use to_number to get number from it.

```
select translate('A1B2C3', 'ABC', '456') from dual;    --result '415263'

select to_number(translate('A1B2C3', 'ABC', '456')) from dual;  --result 415263
```

[translate function documentation](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/translate.php)

> The Oracle/PLSQL TRANSLATE function replaces a sequence of characters in a string with another set of characters. However, it replaces a single character at a time.
>   For example, it will replace the 1st character in the string_to_replace with the 1st character in the replacement_string. Then it will replace the 2nd character in the string_to_replace with the 2nd character in the replacement_string, and so on.

Comment: This solution will cause different id's to be assigned the same number. The OP didn't say it, but it is very likely if this operation is to be useful in any way, different ID's should not receive the same numeric value.